How to replace all contents of a folder with all contents of another folder
I want to execute a CMD command in Windows which basically does the following things:

Removes all contents of the destination folder, including (empty) subfolders and files, but not the destination itself
Copies all contents from the source folder to the destination folder, including (empty) subfolders and files - but not the source itself, only its contents

Is there any built-in command in windows which is able to do something like this?
In Linux, with rm -rf destination/* there is a way to delete all contents of a folder, is there a Windows equivalent?

rd /?, xcopy /?, robocopy /?

@Stephan rd does delete the destination itself, which is not my requirement. I have looked into xcopy and robocopy, but obviously they do not delete the contents in my destination.

so cd or pushd to the destination folder. It can't be deleted when it's the current working directory, but removes everything within.

@Stephan Thanks, I will give it a try. What exactly is the difference between copy, xcopy and robocopy?

copy is the oldest tool, designed for copying files. xcopy is not that old and designed to copy files and folders. robocopy is the newest of the three and has an overwhelming amount of options and switches (you might be especially interested in the /MIR switch). Read their help information.

@Stephan robocopy /mir was exactly what I was looking for! Would you mind posting your infos as an answer so I can accept it?

As mentioned in a comment, robocopy /MIR was exactly what I searched for.
